# Concrete5 - Sitemap Search Selector does not properly paginate

Tags: concrete5

The sitemap search selector overlay (e.g. "Select Page") does not properly paginate when over 100 children pages are present.

The pagination appears, but click "Next >" or a number does not change the sitemap in anyway. The issue appears in both Chrome and Firefox (haven't tested others).

The issue is present in both "Full sitemap" and "Flat view".

Some solution state to add `define('SITEMAP_PAGES_LIMIT',200);` to the `config/site.php`. Those answers however date from 2012 and since the `site.php` has been removed.

Currently using Concrete5 version 8.3.1.

How can I increase the number of paginated pages shown in the page selector?

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: How can I increase the number of paginated pages shown in the page selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the config key `concrete.limits.sitemap_pages`.
The default value is **100** and is located in concrete/config/concrete.php:1078.

You can override it simple by adding a similar php array in your `application/config/concrete.php` file.